# Is it possible to rewrite to a URL with a fragment in it in nginx?

Tags: nginx

E.g.

rewrite ^/page /#page;

I'm not sure if this would even be possible, due to the nature of fragments (never sent to the server etc). But since I'm rewriting TO one, rather than FROM one, I think it should work?

In which case how do I encode/escape that hash sign so that it doesn't start a comment..?

Thanks!

Comment: It needs to be an *external* redirect - so add the `redirect` or `permanent` suffix to the `rewrite` statement.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "external"in this case? And how do I encode the hash/pound sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, the fragment is used by the browser and is not sent to the server.

But you can use `nginx` to rewrite a request into a new URI containing a fragment, but it only makes sense if the new URI is sent to the browser, i.e by using an HTTP 3xx response.

The `rewrite` directive will generate an HTTP 3xx response when the `redirect` (302) or `permanent` (301) flag is provided (or the replacement string starts with a scheme - see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more).

For example:

```
rewrite ^/page /#page redirect;
```

Comment: Great, thanks. How do I avoid the # starting a comment though?

Comment: Oh ok, turns out it's not something I have to worry about!

Answer (score 0):

Adding quotation marks, could help. I tried in Docker Nginx latest image (1.17.4)

```
rewrite ^/page "/#page" redirect;
```